# Why does the pygame window not close properly?

Tags: python, pygame

When I go to close the program window, the program freezes, then I am  forced to force quit the program. Why doesn't the program close when the X / Close button is clicked on.
I am also using python 2.7 if that matters.

```
import pygame
import os, sys
from itertools import *
from oryxsprites import *
from oryxbackground import *

running = True


while running:

    backgroundmain()
    pygame.display.set_caption('OryxGame')
    #pygame.display.set_icon(biggrasstile)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quote from [an article that sports code very similar to yours](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/creating-pygame-window):

> The window now persists whilst 'running' is equal to True, which it
>   will be until you close the window (by clicking the X). Note that if
>   you use an IDE for Python programming, then it may interfere with
>   Pygame. This isn’t normally a major problem but it can stop the Pygame
>   window from closing properly. If so, adding pygame.quit() should solve
>   the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Btw I learned that code from a different tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.2, pygame 1.9 win32, `sys.exit()` is useless (seen on an online tuto).
`pygame.quit()` works perfectly

Comment: The OP is asking about Python 2.7, though - is this the same for both versions?